# "Task timed out after X seconds" error with Lambda AWS and Twilio for WhatsApp message

Tags: amazon-web-services, twilio

I was trying to implement a Lambda function to Send WhatsApp messages with Twilio service.

I have already uploaded the twilio npm package (I was getting the "cannot fin twilio module", but I added the layer and I don't get the error anymore). I'm using node 14 and my zipped npm package is with the nodejs/node_modules... structure (not the node14, but I understood it can work with both). Maybe this is why it's not working?

I got stuck after that. I keep getting the "taks timed out". I changed from the default 3 to 5 seconds, but it still gets errors.

What am I missing or doing wrong?
This is my code:

```
'use strict';
console.log('Trying to send a WhatsApp message...');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
const accountSid = 'ACa4818d82a4d6----------'; //The hyphens is to hide credentials or phone numbers
const authToken = '7e5d8205968af11----------'; 

const client = require('twilio')("ACa4818d------", "7e5d8205968af11-------");
//I event passed the parameters like this to troubleshoot
 
client.messages 
      .create({ 
         body: 'Hi, there!', 
         from: 'whatsapp:+14------',       
         to: 'whatsapp:+1-------' 
       }) 
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid))
      .done();
};
```

This is the response in Lambda console:

```
Test Event Name
TestCon

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2021-12-05T04:39:26.463Z 74eb5536-7da6-4d96-bf8e-824230c85089 Task timed out after 5.01 seconds"
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 74eb5536-7da6-4d96-bf8e-824230c85089 Version: $LATEST
2021-12-05T04:39:21.452Z    undefined   INFO    Trying to send a WhatsApp message...
END RequestId: 74eb5536-7da6-4d96-bf8e-824230c85089
REPORT RequestId: 74eb5536-7da6-4d96-bf8e-824230c85089  Duration: 5005.62 ms    Billed Duration: 5000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 86 MB  Init Duration: 176.11 ms    
2021-12-05T04:39:26.463Z 74eb5536-7da6-4d96-bf8e-824230c85089 Task timed out after 5.01 seconds

Request ID
74eb5536-7da6-4d96-bf8e-824230c85089
```

Comment: Are you sure that 5 seconds is enough?

Comment: `.then` makes me think that you're working with an API that will return a Promise -- meaning that you need to `await client.messages...`. Also, Lambda can be configured execute for up to 15 minutes -- try a longer timeout? Are you allotting enough memory? Have you tried running the func locally and seeing how long it takes? It's difficult to diagnose this problem without additional info.

Comment: It could be also a networking problem. Does the lambda function run in a VPC? In that case you need to assure internet connectivity (via NAT Gateway for private subnets)

Comment: @MingSlogar Hi! Yes, I changed the timeout for 1 minute and it worked. Now I'm facing a new issue. Could you please, check? I posted a new question, since updating it here would completely change the post.

Comment: @Caféconleche looks like you got a response (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70241983/2179987) that matched my initial comment regarding use of `await`. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await for more on the async/await pattern or https://medium.com/radient-tech-blog/aws-lambda-and-the-node-js-event-loop-864e48fba49 for how Lambda interacts with the Node event loop.

Comment: Yes, the response worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by increasing the timeout time.

I changed from 5 seconds to 1 minute.
Looks like the first request in a while takes around 15 seconds. Request afters that take miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, in AWS Lambda function. I checked Lambda configuration -> General Configuration Timeout was 3 sec, I  increased it using edit button.

[image]